# Controller failed with error code INVALID_JOINTS

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, pick-and-place

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I’m trying to achieve pick and place in gazebo for panda arm by using moveit+rviz to plan motion.
I’m getting below error on the terminal from which i launch moveit_planning _execution.launch file.

```
Controller panda/panda_hand_controller failed with error code INVALID_JOINTS
```

here is my config/controllers.yaml file from moveit side

```
controller_manager_ns: controller_manager
controller_list:
  - name: panda/panda_arm_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    default: true
    joints: 
        - panda_joint1
        - panda_joint2
        - panda_joint3
        - panda_joint4
        - panda_joint5
        - panda_joint6
        - panda_joint7

  - name: panda/panda_hand_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    default: true
    joints:
        - panda_finger_joint1
        - panda_finger_joint2
```

Below is my joint_names.yaml file

```
controller_joint_names: ['panda_joint1', 'panda_joint2', 'panda_joint3', 'panda_joint4', 'panda_joint5', 'panda_joint6', 'panda_joint7', ’panda_finger_joint1’, ’panda_finger_joint2’]
```

About moveit planning groups from setup assistant tool, below are the groups i have created. I’m using panda_arm as planning group in my code

[image: image description]

Can someone tell me how to solve or debug this issue?

---

Update 1

On the terminal from which i spawn gazebo and controllers i get below error

> Joints on incoming goal don't match the controller joints.

My suspect is that these errors are occurring because of following reason

I’m using "panda_arm " as planning group which doesn’t include finger_joints (in this case i’m doing as suggested in moveit_tutorial. ) Here can anyone suggest me how planning group should be in moveit setup_assistant?

---

Update 2

In gazebo, robot approaches the object and when it should open the finger joints( comparing to fake trajectory execution in rviz) robot stops the trajectory execution.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318206/controller-failed-with-error-code-invalid_joints/) by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2019-03-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lab.engineering](https://answers.ros.org/users/40428/lab.engineering/) on 2019-03-11**:
Hey - I think we have the same problem, Running moveit+rviz with the Pandas current ros-melodic-franka-description.
When you run the standard demo.launch do you get a Clump of Panda joints in the center of your workspace?
[Screenshot of MoveIt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qohc8rO8PN-3aN-hMXBaZd4uwwMMFRST/view?usp=sharing)

[MoveIt! Quickstart in RViz](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html)

I've followed the setup assistant and tried making a couple other joint configurations - but nothing yet.   : [Setup_assistant_tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html)

Could it be from the latest melodic-franka-description?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-11**:
@lab.engineering: it's much more likely you're running into #q272692.

**Comment by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) on 2019-03-11**:
@lab.engineering: For me everything works fine in RVIZ. Even with demo.launch i'm able to see pick and place happening in RVIZ. i have problem in gazebo that panda arm  reaches till the pose where it should open up the finger joints but  finger_joints are not moving.

**Comment by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) on 2019-03-11**:
@gvdhoorn: any suggestions on this issue by looking at update 2??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve this issue i would like to note what worked for me.

note: I feel this answer is very specific to panda arm.

**At first why this error comes up?**

If you look into lines 541 to 552 of **joint_trajectory_controller_impl.h**, they are as follows

```
00541   // Goal should specify all controller joints (they can be ordered differently). Reject if this is not the case
00542   using internal::permutation;
00543   std::vector<unsigned int> permutation_vector = permutation(joint_names_, gh.getGoal()->trajectory.joint_names);
00544 
00545   if (permutation_vector.empty())
00546   {
00547     ROS_ERROR_NAMED(name_, "Joints on incoming goal don't match the controller joints.");
00548     control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult result;
00549     result.error_code = control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult::INVALID_JOINTS;
00550     gh.setRejected(result);
00551     return;
00552   }
```

So error comes up because there is a mismatch between controller joints and joints on the trajectory goal which is sent by moveit.

**Second point how did i found it which joint should be removed?**

Upon observing the hand.xacro  file i noticed that panda_finger_joint2 is set to mimic panda_finger_joint1. (If someone wants to read about mimic joint then its [here](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint)) so i suspected that it panda_finger_joint2 is to mimic panda_finger_joint1 then trajectory message sent by moveit should only have entry for panda_finger_joint1 .

Anyone correct me on the reasoning i have given.

---

Originally posted by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) with karma: 104 on 2019-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JGioia](https://answers.ros.org/users/70014/jgioia/) on 2021-02-13**:
Can you explain specifically what you did to fix this? I am having the exact same issue. I do not understand what you mean when you said that you removed the joint. It seems like removing it in the URDF file would cause many more issues.

Edit: https://github.com/erdalpekel/panda_simulation/issues/20 has more details on how to fix this. I used solution 2.